# power shell invoking get-VHD on a remote computer

Tags: powershell

I have a hyperV server that I use to run a powershell script and one of the cmdlets is `Get-VHD -Path "\\SERVER-A\folder\UVHD-profile.vhdx"`
which tried to get info about a VHDX file from a remote serverA (which is the location of all the VHDX files).

If a run the (above) command locally on the hyperV server it runs successfully.

I now want to run the script from another serverB but the `get-vhd` cmdlet requires a functioning installation of hyperV (not only the Powershell module) so I need to run it using `Invoke-Command`. So I run this command on remote serverB:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName hyperV -ScriptBlock {Get-VHD -Path "\\SERVER-A\folder\UVHD-profile.vhdx"}`
but i get an error saying the path doesnt exists (even though the path exists - I copy-pasted it).

interestingly, when I copy the VHDX file from the remote serverA to the hyperV server and run this command from serverB:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName hyperV -ScriptBlock {Get-VHD -Path "C:\user\desktop\UVHD-profile.vhdx"}`

It works fine. It seems like it's not allowed to use the `get-vhd` with a UNC path when you are using  `Invoke-command`

Anybody knows how to overcome this? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to invoke other commands to ServerA? Could be a WinRM issue.

Comment: yes I can. From both the hyperV server and from serverB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is commonly known as the double-hop issue. Essentially, you're hopping from computer A, to computer B, then to computer C, and the authentication isn't passed on from B to C.

This [Microsoft Documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop) describes the issue in more detail and lists several ways to address it.

Comment: Thank you. that definitive opened a new are for me to investigate and learn. i wasn't even aware of this. Bottom line, I made it work with a -ConfigurationName after the script block and some arguments with -ArgumentList